# how to prevent division by 0 in this case?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How can i prevent divison by 0 in this case?

```
round(
(sum(case when e.nome = 'ERRO' then 1 else 0 end) / sum(case when e.nome = 'SUCESSO' then 1 else 0 end))*100,2) as porcent_error
```

i tried this way but don't work

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? Number of error/number of success?

Comment: exactly, this way I can make the percentage of the error rate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest method is to leave out the `else` in the denominator:

```
round( sum(case when e.nome = 'ERRO' then 1 else 0 end) * 100 /
       sum(case when e.nome = 'SUCESSO' then 1 end)), 2
      ) as porcent_error
```

That way, if nothing matches, it returns `NULL` rather than `0` -- and the division is safe.

Comment: if I replace the 0 within 1 it should also work, right?

Comment: @WillianLima . . . That will avoid the divide-by-zero, but it will throw off the entire calcualtion.